# Time complexity for the following loop of code?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I just need someone to explain one line of code for me, I don't really understand. 
* this is just pseudocode

```py
m: = 1, l := 0, s:= 0:
while m <= n do 
    for j = n-m to n do :
      l:= l + 1
    od 
     for j = 1 to [log n] do 
       s: = s +1 
     od 
     m := 3m 
 od
```

I understand the second for loop is log n time, the while loop is log base 3 n time but I am confused on the first for loop? Can someone explain, is that just o(n)? What does j = n-m really do?

Answer (score 1):

The first `for` loop runs from `n-m` to `n`. So it has `m` iterations. In the last iteration of the while loop `m` is basically `n` so it runs linear in `n`. But the overall complexity is better than `O(n log n)`

In total you have this many iterations

```
(1 + log n) + (3 + log n) + (9 + log n) + ... + (n + log n)  ( log_3 n terms )
 = log_3 n * log n + (1 + 3 + 9 + ... + n)   ( n can be written as 3^(log_3 n) )
 = log_3 n * log n + (3^0 + 3^1 + 3^2 + ... + 3^(log_3 n))   (see this as a base 3 number. 11 is smaller than 100)
<= log_3 n * log n + 3^(1 + log_3 n)
 = log_3 n * log n + 3 * n
```

So the dominating term is `n` and thus the overall complexity is `O(n)`.